# Android - ScrollView vs ViewFlipper

Tags: android-scrollview, android, java, android-viewflipper

Здравствуйте! У меня есть ScrollView, схема которого изображена на картинке, где текстом показаны id Layout'ов. Задача состоит в том, что при нажатии на определённую кнопку ScrollView должен плавно прокрутиться до назначенного id. Но в ScrollView я не нашёл метода прокрутки до id, но я знаю, что ещё есть какой-то ViewFlipper.
Что и как будет лучше использовать?

---

[image]

Comment: А что нельзя использовать вместо `ScrollView` `ListView` c последующим применением `postDelayed(Runnable)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В одном из проектов когда-то решал такую же задачу, держите код:

```
public class DeepScrollView extends ScrollView {
        public DeepScrollView(Context context) {
                super(context);
        }

        public DeepScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
        }

        public DeepScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        public void scrollToDeepChild(int viewId) {
                scrollToDeepChild(findViewById(viewId));
        }

        public void scrollToDeepChild(View child) {
                final Point childOffset = new Point();

                getDeepChildOffset(child.getParent(), child, childOffset);

                final Rect childRect = new Rect(childOffset.x, childOffset.y, childOffset.x + child.getWidth(), childOffset.y + child.getHeight());
                final int deltay = computeScrollDeltaToGetChildRectOnScreen(childRect);
                smoothScrollBy(0, deltay + getDeepChildTopMargin(child));
        }

        private void getDeepChildOffset(ViewParent nextParent, View nextChild, Point accumulatedOffset) {
                final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) nextParent;
                accumulatedOffset.x += nextChild.getLeft();
                accumulatedOffset.y += nextChild.getTop();
                if (parent == this) {
                        return;
                }
                getDeepChildOffset(parent.getParent(), parent, accumulatedOffset);
        }

        private int getDeepChildTopMargin(View child) {
                int topMargin = 0;
                if (child.getLayoutParams() instanceof MarginLayoutParams) {
                        topMargin = ((MarginLayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams()).topMargin;
                }
                return topMargin;
        }
}
```

Comment: @falstaf, Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы этот код работал? Если я всё правильно понял, то мой ScrollView нужно как-то привязать к этому классу...

Comment: Просто используйте его вместо `ScrollView`.

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Спасибо.